# find out when job in threadpool is completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a polling service which execute jobs at different interval. Each of these job is an external assembly which performs different actions but they all have a common interface which allows me to call the following every time a job need to be executed

- InitializeJob (called when the service is initialized)
- RunJob (called when the specific interval for that job has elapsed
- FinalizeJob (called when the service is stopped)

When debugging my service, I call the RunJob synchronously but when run as an service, I call the job asynchronously by adding it to a threadpool.

Since the job can be lengthy, it's important for me to ensure that if it is currently running, I don't call the same job again if the timer interval has elapsed for that very same job.

Each job is assigned a uniqueId, so it's easy for me to identify the specific job information which is stored in a dictionary and what I have is something like this:

```
this.PollingJobs[currentJob.JobId].ElaspedTime = 0;
this.PollingJobs[currentJob.JobId].IsProcessing = false;
```

etc...

I set the IsProcessing property to true just before starting a specific job and before allowing it to run again, I always ensure that IsProcessing is false, but how can I reset this property to false only when the specific job which was added to the threadpool is completed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't the the actual Job class (i.e the class that contains/runs the long running code) responsible for updating those properties (IsProcessing, ElapsedTime etc.) ?

Comment: Because the service is the one checking the time and therefore keeping track of all the jobs. I don't see how this would help?? Howerver, you've just given me an idea. I since the object are kept alive in memory and are re-used, I could easily move the IsProcessing to my interface and make that a common property for all jobs, and my service could easily check this. Thanks :)